# difference of variadic argumets and array definition for reflection

Tags: reflection, parameters, variadic

I have the following two pieces of code:

```
public class C {
    public void method1(String[] args) {

    }

    public void method2(String... args) {

    }
}
```

Then I obtain Method instances of the methods above using reflection.

```
Method m1 = nil;
Method m2 = nil;
Class c = Class.forName("C");
for (Method m : c.getMethods()) {
    if (m.getName().equals("method1")) m1 = m;
    if (m.getName().equals("method2")) m2 = m;
}
```

m1.getParameters() and m2.getParameters() return equals lists of Class instances.
argument of m1 and argument of m2 are both represented as arrays. But actually they are not same. Compiler will not allow

```
m1("a", "b");
```

The question is:

Is there any flag that specify whether parameter is variadic or just regular array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class java.lang.reflect.Method has method isVarArg(). It shows whether the last argument of the method is variadic.